# React component timer getting out of sync with number field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

My number field does not sync up with my countdown timer.

I can start the countdown and pause it, but if I try to modify the number value after pausing, the numbers are out of sync. There will be a gap between the two numbers that increases as time continues.

This is regarding the 'duration' and countdowncircletimer below:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { CountdownCircleTimer } from 'react-countdown-circle-timer';
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css';

export default function Spinner({
  setColor,
  color,
  setRotation,
  rotation,
  loop,
  setLoop,
}) {
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(60);
  function handleDurationChange(e) {
    if (e.target.value > 0) {
      setDuration(e.target.value);
    }
  }
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

  const renderTime = ({ remainingTime }) => {
    if (remainingTime === 0 && loop === 'false') {
      setIsPlaying(false);
      return <div className={styles.timer}>Finished</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div className={styles.timer}>
        <div className={styles.text}>Remaining</div>
        <div className={styles.value}>{remainingTime}</div>
        <div className={styles.text}>seconds</div>
      </div>
    );
  };
  const [key, setKey] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className={styles.card}>
      <div>
        <CountdownCircleTimer
          key={key}
          isPlaying={isPlaying}
          duration={duration}
          initialRemainingTime={duration}
          size={350}
          strokeWidth={30}
          colors={color}
          rotation={rotation}
          remainingTime={duration}
          onComplete={() => ({
            shouldRepeat: { loop },
            delay: 0,
            newInitialRemainingTime: { duration },
          })}
        >
          {renderTime}
        </CountdownCircleTimer>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <label className={styles.num} htmlFor='duration'></label>
          <input
            id='duration'
            type='number'
            value={duration}
            onChange={handleDurationChange}
            disabled={isPlaying}
          />
          <br></br>
          <label className={styles.btn} htmlFor='isPlaying'>
            {isPlaying ? 'Pause' : 'Play'}
          </label>
          <input
            id='isPlaying'
            type='checkbox'
            onChange={() =>
              setIsPlaying(!isPlaying) &&
              setDuration(duration) &&
              setColor(color)
            }
          />
          <br></br>
          <label className={styles.btn} htmlFor='reset'>
            Reset
          </label>
          <input
            onClick={() => setKey((prevKey) => prevKey + 1)}
            id='reset'
            type='checkbox'
            onChange={() => setDuration(60) && setColor('#f25758')}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**PHOTO OF PROBLEM**
[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGOS2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because after changing the duration the CountdownCircleTimer still remembers the seconds that have already passed. If you want to restart the timer with the new value you have to update the key. So if you change `handleDurationChange` like this it won't show the gap anymore.

```js
function handleDurationChange(e) {
  if (e.target.value > 0) {
    setDuration(e.target.value);
    setKey(key + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: perfect that does exactly what I wanted! I think I tried about everything other than messing with the key. Thank you so much!